# Enable button after in-app purchase

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, in-app-purchase, xcode8

I have a sharing button ("share") that, after pressing 10 times, will hang up. To unlock it, you must purchase it in app. The trouble is that I'm not able to figure out how to unlock the button when the user buys it. The button must remain unlocked. It should not be blocked after the 10 times it is pressed. The same thing must happen if you press the "restore" button. The button must unlock this, if the user erases the app and reinstalls it. I ask you for help. Here I put the code that runs the purchase in the app and that of the button

Thanks to everyone and apologize for the beginner's question

For convenience I put the 2 files in a shared dropbox link, accessible to everyone
[Dropbox (file swift)](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1kq6gbbkptgb50q/AABGXIzoDhsCbPYC9BYEOPcaa?dl=0)

**CODE BUTTON "SHARE"**

```
var gif : GifModel? = nil


var imgView : UIImageView? = nil


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    imgView = UIImageView(image: UIImage.gifImageWithURL(gif!.url!))
    imgView!.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: gif!.width, height: gif!.height)
    self.view.addSubview(imgView!)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    imgView!.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.view.frame.size.height / 2)
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func createAlert (title: String, message: String) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {
        (action) in alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)}))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


}

@IBAction func share(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {


    var counter: Int = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "yourUniqueKey")
    if counter < 10 {
        self.shareGifs(url: URL(string: gif!.url!)!)
        counter += 1
        UserDefaults.standard.set(counter, forKey: "yourUniqueKey")
    } else {
        sender.isEnabled = false

        // alert qui!!! l'utente ha esaurito i 10 tap!
        createAlert(title: "OPS....", message: "In order to continue to share all the gifs you want and forever, you must purchase the 'Unlimited Gifs' pack")
    }
}
```

**CODE IN-APP PURCHASE**

```
extension IAPHelper {

public func requestProducts(completionHandler: @escaping ProductsRequestCompletionHandler) {
    productsRequest?.cancel()
    productsRequestCompletionHandler = completionHandler

    productsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers)
    productsRequest!.delegate = self
    productsRequest!.start()
}

public func buyProduct(_ product: SKProduct) {
    print("Buying \(product.productIdentifier)...")
    let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
}

public func isProductPurchased(_ productIdentifier: ProductIdentifier) -> Bool {
    return purchasedProductIdentifiers.contains(productIdentifier)
}

public class func canMakePayments() -> Bool {
    return SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()
}

public func restorePurchases() {
    SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
}
```

}

```
extension IAPHelper: SKProductsRequestDelegate {

public func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    let products = response.products
    print("Loaded list of products...")
    productsRequestCompletionHandler?(true, products)
    clearRequestAndHandler()

    for p in products {
        print("Found product: \(p.productIdentifier) \(p.localizedTitle) \(p.price.floatValue)")
    }
}

public func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print("Failed to load list of products.")
    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    productsRequestCompletionHandler?(false, nil)
    clearRequestAndHandler()
}

private func clearRequestAndHandler() {
    productsRequest = nil
    productsRequestCompletionHandler = nil
}
```

}

```
extension IAPHelper: SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

public func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction in transactions {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
        case .purchased:
            complete(transaction: transaction)
            break
        case .failed:
            fail(transaction: transaction)
            break
        case .restored:
            restore(transaction: transaction)
            break
        case .deferred:
            break
        case .purchasing:
            break
        }
    }
}

private func complete(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
    print("complete...")
    deliverPurchaseNotificationFor(identifier: transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
}

private func restore(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
    guard let productIdentifier = transaction.original?.payment.productIdentifier else { return }

    print("restore... \(productIdentifier)")
    deliverPurchaseNotificationFor(identifier: productIdentifier)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
}

private func fail(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
    print("fail...")
    if let transactionError = transaction.error as NSError? {
        if transactionError.code != SKError.paymentCancelled.rawValue {
            print("Transaction Error: \(String(describing: transaction.error?.localizedDescription))")
        }
    }

    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
}

private func deliverPurchaseNotificationFor(identifier: String?) {
    guard let identifier = identifier else { return }

    purchasedProductIdentifiers.insert(identifier)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: identifier)
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: IAPHelper.IAPHelperPurchaseNotification), object: identifier)
}
```

}

Comment: Please put the relevant code in your question

Comment: I have no problem putting it but it is long. I preferred to simplify putting on dropbox for this reason. Anyway I put it now

Comment: done ;) Added code

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to store a value into NSUserDefaults when the purchase happens, and then your view is loaded, do a simple check for the value to see if it has been purchased and then limit, or not, the number of presses that can happen.

Set it inside of your completion code

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"IAPPurcashed"
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"IAP" object:self];
```

Then in your view

```
([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] bookForKey:@"IAPPurcashed"] == YES 
{
    *unlock IAP for multiple presses*
}
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(ReloadIAPButton:) name:@"IAP" object:nil];``
```

Also add your observer for the notification center to reload any buttons you may need.

Comment: in swift please... :(